# Why won't VSCode debugger allow me to set a breakpoint?

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am a self taught programmer new to typescript.
With the vscode debugger running  I am able to place a breakpont on line 291 and the function works as intended.
However when I try to place a breakpoint in the second function on line 298 it moves the breakpoint to line 300 and the function does not transfer control on line 299.
The code is part of a html web page running in chrome with a http-localserver.
When I inspect the equivalent javascript code, chrome will also not allow me to place a breakpoint on the equivalent javascript line.
I do not understand what is different between the two functions.

[Code in Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3J6f.png)

Comment: It often is because the Javascript being executed or the source map is out of date. Try stopping the debugger, recompiling the Typescript and starting the debugger again.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is what I achieved by closing vscode and restarting again.

Answer (score -1):

I closed vscode. When I re-started vscode I could place the breakpoint and the second function worked as expected.  No changes were made to the code.